# How to approximate the arc length of curve C using computational method?

Tags: matlab

Using this arc length formula:

[image: Using this arc length formula]

1. How to complete the code to calculate the interval distance?
2. How to edit this code to calculate 2D arc length of the ellipse with the same number of intervals?

```
a=0;
b=1;
Nint=100;
Npoints=Nint+1;
tvals=linspace(a,b,Npoints);
p=zeros(Npoints,3); %2 for 2d

t_to_coord=@(t) [t,t^2,t^3];

for i=1:Npoints
    p(i,:)=t_to_coord(tvals(i));
end

plot3(p(:,1),p(:,2),p(:,3))

intervaldists=zeros(Nint,1);
%%calculate interval distance
for i=1:Nint
    intervaldists(i) = %complete here
end

curvelength = sum(intervaldists);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not having matlab I can't check my syntax but this is the idea:

```
for i=1:Nint-1
    intervaldists(i) = sqrt((p(i+1,1)-p(i,2))^2+(p(i+1,2)-p(i,1))^2+(p(i+1,3)-p(i,3))^2)
end
```

Namely, find the Euclidean distance |p_(i+1)-p_i| using sqrt( (x2-x1)^2+(y2-y1)^2+(z2-z1)^2)

You can probably do this without the loop using Matlab's vectorized ability , e.g. something along the lines of

```
p_shifted = p[2:] 
intervaldists = sqrt(sum((p_shifted-p)^2))
```

but you;ll have to take care of the last point - and I don't recall Matlab syntax too well so I'm not sure if I have the indexing right.

Comment: If you feel this answered your question you're invited to hit the 'check' button